# How to use srand and rand to continuously generate new numbers?

Tags: c, random, srand

In my main funtion, the function fragment below is looped to keep generating two numbers between 0 and 4. The first time it goes through the loop it works fine, but the second time it gets core dumped. I'm not sure if it's because of a bug somewhere else or if I just didn't use the rand and srand properly. Very new to c language here.

```
void generate_player2_move(char board[][SIZE], int row, int col) {
    //segmentation fault (core dumped) somewhere around here.
    int randrow, randcol;
    srand((unsigned) randrow);
    srand((unsigned) randcol);  

    row = rand() % 4;
    col = rand() % 4;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: @Gilles Oh ok! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The code you've shown doesn't do anything that could cause a core dump, so that's probably in code you haven't shown.  You are however using `srand` incorrectly.

Random numbers returned by the `rand` function are actually a sequence of numbers that are passed through a function, with the last output being the new input.  This function needs to be seeded before it runs for the first time, and that's what the `srand` function does.

You should be calling `srand` only once at the beginning of your program.  After that, just call `rand` whenever you need a new random number.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you!